# www-data user cannot generate gpg key

Tags: debian, gpg

I am trying to [set up passbolt](https://help.passbolt.com/hosting/install/ce/debian-9-stretch.html) on a Debian 9 KVM guest, and one of the steps is to generate a GPG key as the www-data user. Unfortunately, whenever I try to do this (by running `gpg --gen-key` as the www-data user), I get the following output:

```
...
Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? o
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: agent_genkey failed: Permission denied
Key generation failed: Permission denied
```

The home directory for the `www-data` user is `/var/www` and the user has read-write permission there. If I run `gpg --list-keys` (as the www-data user) beforehand, it successfully creates the `/var/www/.gnupg` directory, so its not like the user doesn't have the correct permissions there.

What do I need to do in order to generate a GPG key as the www-data user?

### Appendix

The env output if I log into www-data using `sudo su www-data`:

```
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SUDO_GID=1000
USERNAME=root
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su www-data
USER=www-data
PWD=/home/stuart
HOME=/var/www
SUDO_USER=stuart
SUDO_UID=1000
MAIL=/var/mail/www-data
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=www-data
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
_=/usr/bin/env
```

The env output if I log in using `sudo su - www-data`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
USER=www-data
PWD=/var/www
HOME=/var/www
MAIL=/var/mail/www-data
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=www-data
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
_=/usr/bin/env
```

The env output if I log in using `ssh www-data@mydomain.com`

```
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.16.155 50692 192.168.16.152 22
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=11
USER=www-data
PWD=/var/www
HOME=/var/www
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.16.155 50692 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
MAIL=/var/mail/www-data
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=www-data
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/33
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: what is the exact command that you are running ?

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET `gpg --gen-key`, it asks for name, then email address, then confirmation for okay, then fails at the point where the gpg-agent would notrmall ask for a passphrase to encrypt the key with, that prompt never appears

Comment: Ok, but I mean do you use sudo ? or su ? or how do you become www-data to execute that command. Can you add the details to the post please ?

Comment: I don't use sudo, I literally use `gpg --gen-key`. I became the www-data user by changing `/etc/passwd` so that www-data uses /bin/bash instead of nologin and then doing `sudo su www-data`, but the same situation applies when I created another user to test with who is also a non-sudo user. (created user using sudo adduser testuser)

Answer (score 9):

This is a symptom of GPG's `pinentry` program requiring user ownership of the tty device.  The failure in this example happens when `pinentry` would prompt for a password for the newly generated key.

From the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#su):

> When using `pinentry`, you must have the proper permissions of the
> terminal device (e.g. `/dev/tty1`) in use. However, with su (or sudo),
> the ownership stays with the original user, not the new one. This
> means that pinentry will fail with a `Permission denied` error, even
> as root.
>
> ...
>
> The fix is to change the permissions of the device at some point
> before the use of pinentry (i.e. using gpg with an agent).

You can check the permissions of the terminal device in use with:

`ls -l $(tty)`

You will see that the file is owned by the user that first used `sudo`/`su`, not the current user.

Change the ownership of the terminal device (*probably needs to be done as root*; **don't forget to change it back when you're done**) with, e.g.:

`chown www-data /dev/pts/0`

Now `pinentry` will work correctly and the key generation process should complete successfully.

---

**NB**

It is not enough for the the user to be able to read/write the terminal device file, *it must have user ownership set to the user attempting to use `pinentry`*.

---

It's also possible to create a new GPG setup as any user and transfer it to any other user.

`GNUPGHOME=/home/user/gpg-alt gpg --gen-key`

Run through the setup like normal.  Then copy the new setup to the other user and make sure to set the permissions appropriately.

```bsh
# run as root
mv /home/user/gpg-alt /home/www-data/.gnupg
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/www-data/.gnupg
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you cannot generate keys if you logged into a user account using `sudo su [user]`. However, if you SSH into the server as that user, e.g. `ssh www-data@mydomain.com`, then `gpg --gen-key` will work.

Comment: did you try with `sudo su - user` ?

Comment: I just tried that, and that didn't work either.

Comment: do you mind running `env` after having connected by ssh and by running sudo ?

Comment: Looks like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802525/unable-to-generate-gpg-keys-in-linux

Comment: I can see how you think its similar, but it looks like he is having a different issue with the error being: `gpg: problem with the agent: Timeout  ` whereas for me its a permission denied issue.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I added the env info as an appendix to the question.

Comment: thanks, but can you put the `sudo su - www-data` please ?

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET done

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to create gpg key as the user did not seem to have the permission, hence I was getting:

```
gpg: agent_genkey failed: Permission denied
Key generation failed: Permission denied
```

I was able to resolve this by changing permissions for the current user say myuser:

```
chown myuser /dev/pts/0
```

(This needs to be done at the root level)

Once the permission is provided, I was able to create keys for my user.

Comment: This answer needs an explanation of where `/dev/pts/0` comes into things. (It's likely related to trying to read a passphrase from the user; but that begs the question of what's wrong with `/dev/tty` on your system.)